# MySQL only bring back latest record

Tags: mysql, group-by, max, sql-order-by

I have a table which stores rows with some fields being the id, name, date and version. I could have two rows with same `name` but a different version, so a file can have multiple versions.

My query:

```
 SELECT id, name, date, version FROM my_table AS a
```

Example output (each new line is another row):

```
1 | abc.xls | 1488363249 | 1
2 | example.xls | 1488363232 | 1
3 | thirdfile.xls | 1488362312 | 1
4 | thirdfile.xls | 1488363249 | 2
```

What i want to do is only bring back the following:

```
1 | abc.xls | 1488363249 | 1
2 | example.xls | 1488363232 | 1
4 | thirdfile.xls | 1488363249 | 2
```

What happened was it noticed id 3 and 4 were the same filename and it only brought back version 2 as it was the latest of that filename

How would I achieve this in a single query.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work

```
SELECT t.id, t.name, t.date, t.version
FROM my_table t
JOIN (SELECT max(version) max_version, name FROM my_table GROUP BY name) t1
  ON t.version= t1.max_version AND t.name= t1.name
```